# WebEngine load html file in a JavaFx application

Tags: java, html, javafx, javafx-8

I'm doing a java program for university.
I'm tryng to open a new stage when click on a button on the menu item.
This stage have to show the content of a html file.

To open the stage is not a problem, the problem is that the stage is empty (I don't get any error while opening the stage).

[html stage (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcR1K.png)

In the main controller of the java program this is the code to open the html-stage:

```
@FXML
public void showBrowser(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("othello/view/browser.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Team Background");
    primaryStage.show();
} }
```

This is the fxml file of the html-stage that I want to show (browser.fxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="othello.controller.WebViewController">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" layoutX="100.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is the controller's code of the fxml file (WebViewController) :

```
package othello.controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class WebViewController {
   @FXML
   public WebView webView;
   public WebEngine webEngine;

   private void initialize() {

webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/Othello/src/othello/html/TeamBackground/history.html").toExternalForm());



    }
}
```

I've also tried loading as URL or as File using the path of the .hmtl file without any result.
Could you help me ?

Best Regards.

Comment: The path to the HTML file is  almost certainly wrong: the `src` folder is extremely unlikely to be accessible at runtime.

Comment: which would be a correct path ?
thank you.

Comment: No idea: you haven't shown your project layout. Probably `getClass().getResource("/othello/html/...")` will work, if everything else is set up the way it looks like it is.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement like your code and i found your mistake ,you used wrong path of html file you started from src folder,but when you use getClass().getResource() ,you are currently in resource folder **src** so correct your path to:

```
  webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/othello/html/TeamBackground/history.html").toExternalForm());
```